# Why does returning a value, then using it as a variable not work in Python this way?

Tags: python, function, variables, return, return-value

```
import time
def planeFun ():
    print("The plane has spiked your intrest")
    print("  s    ")
    skully=input("You ran a couple feet away, are you going to go look back in?\n")
    if skully in ["Yes", "yes", " yes", " Yes", "y", "Y", "ya"]:
        print("You decide to go and check back in, make sure what you saw is real!")
        goin=input("should you investigate the plane more, or run away?\n")
        return goin


planeFun()

result= planeFun()
if result in ["run", "Run", " run", " Run", "run away", "Run away", " run away", " Run away"]:
    print("You decide to leave, something weird is going on, and you're not sticking around to find out")
```

What have I done wrong in this program? I have tried to fix it and couldn't. Whenever 'run' is entered, the program re runs the function, and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: `result = planeFun()`. Also you misspelled `result` in: `if reslut in ...`

Comment: Double check your spellings and please make an edit to explain *what* has gone wrong exactly. My bet is on a `NameError: name 'reslut' is not defined`

Comment: you could convert to lower case+strip your tests would be less tedious... `skully=input("You ran a couple feet away, are you going to go look back in?\n").lower().strip()`

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean "Whenever 'run' is entered, the program reruns the function"??? You specifically call the function twice...

Comment: That is the problem, but it doesn't make sense, I need someone to explain why this is happening.

Comment: Based on your code, you are calling the function twice regardless of whether run is entered...is your problem that you're seeing the function run twice?

Comment: @QuestionedE I still don't understand the problem. Can you explain **exactly** what's going on, and perhaps more importantly, what you *expect* to happen?

Comment: @QuestionedE Because you are calling it twice, remove the first `planeFun()` by itself.

Comment: jean-Francois Fabre, what exactly would that do, I am still fairly new to python?

Comment: @QuestionedE it would only run the function once

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thank you so much! If you put that as the answer, I can mark it as resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whenever 'run' is entered, the program re runs the function, and I cannot figure out why.

This is due to the function `planeFun` getting called twice:

```
planeFun()          # <-- 1

result= planeFun()  # <-- 2
```

Along with this I'd recommend what *@Jean-François Fabre* mentioned in the comments. Removing trailing and leading white space and making your input not case sensitive can make it easier to check for certain results:

```
def planeFun ():
    print("The plane has spiked your intrest")
    print("  s    ")
    skully=input("You ran a couple feet away, are you going to go look back in?\n").lower().strip()
```

That way you only need to check for lowercase text and you can remove the upper case duplicate checks.

Answer (score 3):

Second to last line, you typed:

```
`if reslut in ...`
```

Try with result.

Comment: either way though, when run is entered, the program reruns the function...

Comment: this is probably not the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should fill the "else" statement for debugging, means print skully if the input is not yes
same for result